If $X(t)$ is Ergodic, what about $X^2(t)$?
Given:
${X(t)}$ is W.S.S, Gauss with expected value $=0$, which has $R_{XX}(\tau)$
So $C_{XX}(\tau)=R_{XX}(\tau)$
$\int_0^{\infty}R_{XX}\left(\tau\right)d\tau<\infty$, since $X(t)$ is Ergodic.
Problem is, according to my HW ( with solution, partially but not explained ), they used other way to prove, but not clear also.
If I try to use Ergodic for $X^2(t)$, I will receive:
$\int_0^{\infty}2R_{XX}\left(\tau\right)^2d\tau<\infty$
I did not show a way to receive it, but trust me, it is true.
Why can I say that $X^2(t)$ is ergodic when I use this? what is the relationship between $R_{XX}(\tau)$ and $R_{XX}(\tau)^2$
